# Как прицепиться к окну?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

Можно ли как то привязать окно моей программы к окну другой программы?

Пока я знаю только об одном способе, в цикле while вычислять текущие координаты окна и изменять координаты своего окна. Но, может, есть возможность получать оповещения об изменении положения окна стороннего приложения через Win_API?

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо установить parent для твоего окна в качестве другого окна при помощи WniAPI функции:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);
```

Comment: ну окно становится дочерним... как в MDI приложениях. Со всеми вытекающими. А мне надо, чтобы мое окно таки было снаружи, а не внутри.